# Switching away from mixing static and shared libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries, object-library

I have a project where I mix between static and shared libs. The shared libs are delivered. Each shared lib is built with its correspondence static lib. A shared lib can depend on other shared libs as well. For example, I have: `sharedA`, `sharedB`, `sharedC`, `staticA`, `staticB` and `staticC`. `SharedA` is built with `staticA` inside and similar for other shared. Let's say `sharedC`, besides its dependency on `staticC`, also depends on `sharedB`.

For the static libraries, if they need dependency on another static one, I link against the one's correspondence shared lib. For example:

`staticB` depends on `staticA`. Hence, I link `staticB` against `sharedA`. The reason for this is to avoid size increase if statically declare staticB's dependency on `staticA`.

This system has been working. However, problem arises when I build the static libs with hidden visibility. The linker links with no error. But more than one symbols of a specific class might end up in the final symbol map. Therefore, the program can pick up the undesired one, which causes weird behaviour.

I have been reading about cmake object library, and probably switching the static libs to object libs could help in this case. I change the static libs to object, and get undefined symbol errors. I define dependency of an object lib on other, but still could not get rid of all the errors. My questions are:

1. I am using `target_link_libraries(obj2 PUBLIC obj)` to declare dependency between 2 object libs. Can this be the reason for undefined symbol error I get? Because according to cmake documentation:

> Object Libraries may "link" to other object libraries to get usage requirements, but since they do not have a link step nothing is done with their object files.

2. Maybe I should switch to `target_link_libraries(obj2 $<TARGET_OBJECTS:obj>)` so `obj2` is built with object files from `obj.c`? Another thing with this is: `obj` needs to be a library (created with `add_library`). In the function where I define all the links, `obj` is a variable and could not be put after `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:`. I have been looking around but not able to find anything. Is there a way I can put variable name after `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:`, or I have to refractor somehow to make this possible?
3. Any other suggestion on how to do this would be helpful to me

Comment: What I'm confused about: Static libraries don't link other static libraries. (Both libraries have to be linked into the executable instead.) This is unrelated to the fact that there might be a dependency which you have to express, of course, in CMake.

Comment: Do you mean I should edit my wording? When I say staticB depends on staticA, I mean B needs to be built with symbols from A. Instead of embedding both staticA and staticB inside the binary of sharedB (which already has staticB inside), I link staticB with sharedA (which already contains staticA). By doing this, sharedB does not contain staticA. Do I answer your question?

Comment: I must admit it's a long time ago that I used static linking last time. There is an `option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries" ON)` to build DLLs for any lib. project. (I'm on Windows.) _embedding both staticA and staticB inside the binary of sharedB_ ??? I'm used to build either a static or a dynamic library. If a static library (`staticA`) is linked to a DLL (`sharedB`) it's in fact "embedded". (DLLs are actually like EXEs on Windows. I don't know how this is in case of shared objects in Linux.) However, in CMake you provide dependencies, that's it.

Comment: ... The rest is subject of the generated build scripts and the resp. tool chain. `target_link_libraries(obj2 PUBLIC obj)` sounds reasonable. (This is what we use always in any of our project.)

Comment: Btw. on Windows, the outcome for `staticA` as static lib. would be `staticA.lib`. As shared lib. it would be `staticA.dll` and `staticA.lib`. In the latter case, the `staticA.lib` is not the static library but a (quite small) library, other applications can link against to get link symbols for the DLL. (That's actually everything what was exported from the DLL.) So, if you support static _and_ shared libraries, care of your library names so that the `.lib` files can be distinguished.

Comment: I think we are not on the same page. What I mean is: `target_link_libraries(staticB PUBLIC sharedA)`. With this line, the symbols of staticA is linked with staticB, but staticA won't be in sharedB when I do `target_link_libraries(sharedB PUBLIC staticB)`

Comment: This is yet another thing, I'm confused about: I would link everything shared. In the past, we linked everything static. I could live with a shared lib. where dependencies are statically linked in (although I would prevent this when possible). But a static lib. with a dependency to a shared lib.? I couldn't imagine any case where I would do this (except the shared lib. is a system or 3rd party lib.)

Comment: `target_link_libraries(sharedB PUBLIC staticB)` And this looks even more suspicious. (I tried to explain why this shouldn't be necessary. It seems I wasn't that lucky...) :-(

Comment: Yes, I agree mixing them means asking for more trouble. That's the reason why I am investigating switching the static libs to object. But you suggest trying to change them to shared?

Comment: If you intend to deliver shared libs only, I would built up the CMake project straight forward, and not consider anything static. I believe as well that mixing static and shared is asking for trouble...